# Iterate over directories and subdirectories recursively showing 'path/file' in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, recursion

I am using the code below to iterate recursively over files of directories and subfolders:

```
Dir.glob("**/*").each do |file|

    filename = "#{File.basename(file)}"
    output = `git log -1 -r -n 1 --pretty=format:\"%h: #{filename}\" -- #{filename}`

end
```

The result I am getting from this iteration looks like this:

```
Actual Output:
<The format I choose>: folder1
<The format I choose>: a_file
<The format I choose>: folder2
<The format I choose>: a_file 
<The format I choose>: another_file 
<The format I choose>: folder3
<The format I choose>: a_file
```

While the form I want is below.

```
Expected Output:
    <The format I choose>: folder1/a_file
    <The format I choose>: folder2/a_file
    <The format I choose>: folder2/another_file
    <The format I choose>: folder3/a_file
```

Can you point and explain my error in the loop?

Comment: Can you complete the code at the top of the question - i.e. what's after `.each do |file|`

Comment: @IsmailM I added the code.

Comment: let me know if my answer solves your issue - if so please select the question as solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the reason is that you are running `File.basename` which gives you the 'basename' of the File and not the relative path.

Additionally the `.glob("**/*")` also includes directories and as such you need to take that into account.

This is how I would do it...

```
Dir.glob("**/*").each do |file|
   next if File.directory?(file) # skip the loop if the file is a directory
   puts file
   output = `git log -1 -r -n 1 --pretty=format:"%cd [%h]" -- #{file}`
   puts output  
end
```

Let me know if you want me to explain any line in the above code...